# Script for copy over values only via button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In this sheet, I have some boxes which calculate information, (Columns K:BO)
I have drawn a button next to each box (ADD LINE) 
I need a script attached to the button that will transfer only the information in the coloured cells from each box across to a "Collection Box' in Column (DC:DK)
Each box calculates differently and sometimes I may not need information from all boxes at once hence a button for each one.

The goal is to be able to organise the information so I'm able to copy and paste the information the from the Collection Box (DC:DK) as needed so I don't have to painstakingly extract the information bit by bit

For Example...
I have made a box in Columns  CF:CN  which only mirrors the information I require.
Problem is when I'm not using certain rows the information gets hard to read because of the cluster,
As you might see I've tried to overcome this with basic cell formatting to highlight the information that I'm using at the time

Also the cells in columns CF:CN has cell references applied so I can change the output in columns as needed.
This would be ideal for me to keep.
I'm not sure on the boundaries of the script, but is there a way that when the information is copied to the collection box so it can still utilize the cell reference to change the information without me having to re-enter?

Here is Sheet
Information is in Update Price Tab

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UdYCqgKEGJeh4KajxQWfTCi-JRpQgGM7435Q_VwHIH8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

a script for copy-over values only is:

```
function moveValuesOnly() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A1');
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Sheet1!B1'), {contentsOnly: true}); }
```

this particular one will copy values from **Sheet1!A1** to **Sheet1!B1** if attached to a button

Comment: ok, if I hit the button again will it copy to next set of cells or overwrite the first?